Amplify Gen2 walkthrough works in sandbox, but fails to deploy - TodoList.tsx type errors on build
I have a new Amplify app, created by following the official Amplify Gen 2 walkthrough, working in a sandbox. It will not deploy due to errors during the build (see below).
For what it's worth, it takes about 12 hours of debugging to get through the official Amplify Gen2 "quickstart" tutorial (first time through), because not one command in the instructions works as advertised.
To recreate the error (using a freshly created Cloud9 environment on an upgraded EC2 instance, because the standard free tier machine without an expanded EBS volume will fail - both due to insufficient RAM and insufficient disk, despite Amazon's claims to the contrary, combined with a newly bootstrapped Amplify app and a new CodeCommit repository - everything clean):

Start with this - https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/start/quickstart/vite-react-app/
Work through all the bugs (beyond the scope of this question) and get the system to work locally with a sandbox.
Get the whole thing loaded into a Git repository (in this case, CodeCommit) and link the Amplify app to the repository.
Run the deployment (manually or automatic upon a Git push, if everything is working).
Deployment fails.

Default options and settings and versions are used in all cases, unless specifically mentioned in the linked walkthrough or if needed to fix one of the numerous errors.
The resulting error looks like this:
 170 2024-05-01T22:08:22.641Z [INFO]: src/components/TodoList.tsx(14,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }[]>'.
 171 Type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }[]'.
 172 Property 'type' is missing in type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }' but required in type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }'.
 173 2024-05-01T22:08:22.645Z [INFO]: src/components/TodoList.tsx(20,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }[]>'.
 174 Type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }[]'.
 175 Type '{ readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; owner?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }'.
 176 src/components/TodoList.tsx(42,25): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }'.
 177 src/components/TodoList.tsx(42,35): error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type '{ type: { readonly id: string; readonly createdAt: string; readonly updatedAt: string; } & { content?: Nullable<string> | undefined; done?: Nullable<boolean> | undefined; priority?: "low" | ... 3 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; }; }'.
 178 2024-05-01T22:08:22.710Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
 179 2024-05-01T22:08:22.711Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 2

TodoList.tsx is a direct copy and paste from the tutorial:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/data";
import type { Schema } from "../../amplify/data/resource";

export default function TodoList() {
  // generate your data client using the Schema from your backend
  const client = generateClient<Schema>();

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Schema["Todo"][]>([]);

  async function listTodos() {
    // fetch all todos
    const { data } = await client.models.Todo.list();
    setTodos(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  listTodos()
  const sub = client.models.Todo.observeQuery().subscribe(({ items }) =>
   setTodos([...items])
  );

  return () => sub.unsubscribe();
}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <button onClick={async () => {
        // create a new Todo with the following attributes
        const { errors, data: newTodo } = await client.models.Todo.create({
          // prompt the user to enter the title
          content: window.prompt("title"),
          done: false,
          priority: 'medium'
        })
        console.log(errors, newTodo);
      }}>Create</button>

      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li key={todo.id}>{todo.content}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

../../amplify/data/resource is directly from AWS and looks like this:
import { type ClientSchema, a, defineData } from '@aws-amplify/backend';

/*== STEP 1 ===============================================================
The section below creates a Todo database table with a "content" field. Try
adding a new "isDone" field as a boolean. The authorization rule below
specifies that any user authenticated via an API key can "create", "read",
"update", and "delete" any "Todo" records.
=========================================================================*/

const schema = a.schema({
  Todo: a
    .model({
      content: a.string(),
    })
    .authorization((allow) => [allow.guest()]),
});

export type Schema = ClientSchema<typeof schema>;
export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: 'iam',
  },
});

/*== STEP 2 ===============================================================
Go to your frontend source code. From your client-side code, generate a
Data client to make CRUDL requests to your table. (THIS SNIPPET WILL ONLY
WORK IN THE FRONTEND CODE FILE.)
Using JavaScript or Next.js React Server Components, Middleware, Server 
Actions or Pages Router? Review how to generate Data clients for those use
cases: https://docs.amplify.aws/gen2/build-a-backend/data/connect-to-API/

=========================================================================*/

/*
"use client"
import { generateClient } from "aws-amplify/data";
import type { Schema } from "@/amplify/data/resource";
const client = generateClient<Schema>() // use this Data client for CRUDL requests
*/

/*== STEP 3 ===============================================================
Fetch records from the database and use them in your frontend component.
(THIS SNIPPET WILL ONLY WORK IN THE FRONTEND CODE FILE.)
=========================================================================*/

/* For example, in a React component, you can use this snippet in your
  function's RETURN statement */

// const { data: todos } = await client.models.Todo.list()
// return <ul>{todos.map(todo => <li key={todo.id}>{todo.content}</li>)}</ul>

Since this all works in the sandbox, it seems like there must be some version difference between all the stuff installed for the sandbox compared to what gets deployed and used to build.
One problem I solved (as part of step 2) was the failure of npx amplify sandbox, it was segfaulting and core dumping. This is apparently due to an issue with Node 20.12, so you must fall back to 20.11. I thought this might be the source of the issue, so I added some commands to do that fallback in the amplify.yml (Amplify app->Hosting->build options), with no success. I did not try doing the same thing by specifying a custom build container, as that seems redundant and unnecessary if the amplify.yml approach didn't help. It was using the specified version, according to the console printout.
This has been exhausting and has eaten up a really excessive amount of time. I'd really like to just get this sorted out quickly.

What is the likely culprit?
Why would the sandbox differ from the deployment environment? Isn't the whole point of the sandbox and Amplify broadly, to align all this stuff?

For what it's worth, the Cloud9 IDE is littered with warnings, mostly they seem to be similar type errors. An alleged fix for this is to change the Typescript version setting in the IDE to match the command-line/sandbox enviroment, but there doesn't seem to be such a setting (most people only talk about using VSCode, not Cloud9). Regardless of these warnings (errors?) being left unresolved, the Amplify sandbox eventually worked as intended.
It's quite infuriating that I should need to debug official sample code and that a tutorial meant to take an hour or so requires many hours of debugging, since not a single instruction worked without errors. The Amplify Gen1 tutorial did not work either, but I gave up on it and never resolved those issues, abandoning it in favor of Gen2.

Just wanted to add that it looks like AWS Amplify are working on a similar issue.
In the meantime, using:
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<any[]>([]);
has allowed me to build and deploy. Ugly, but it works for now.
